# How to achieve the selecting effect of NSDatePicker by NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsdatepicker

I wanna implement a custom TextField and its behavior just like NSDatePicker with its own data format, like `00:00:10:25`

[image]

The requirement is as following:

1. It should select text like NSDatePicker.
2. Support the same mouse and keyboard operation, such as changing select when key `←` or `→` is pressed, adjusting value when `↑` or `↓` is pressed...and so on.

This is what I want to implement:

[image]

I'll appreciate so much if someone could guide me how to implement it, or give me some hint.

Comment: And exactly what have you tried?

Comment: @chirag90 I have tried subclassing NSTextField and implement NSTextViewDelegate to achieve select like NSDatePicker. But there are still some issues I can't resolve.

Comment: show you code and what error you are getting

Comment: Try to implement a UIPickerView instead of UITextField. Here is a nice tutorial:
https://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/

Comment: It seems to me that obvious choices are to (1) subclass NSDatePicker to change its behavior, or (2) subclass NSTokenField to try to add in DatePicker type functionality. The latter seems more feasible, if you can figure out how to connect an incrementor to the selected token.